# How can create a new column in Google BigQuery with SQL that is based on a calculation of existing columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some BigQuery code that is pulling the number of users who start a session on a website and the number of successful sessions from google analytics. The code is creating a temporary table.

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE
    WHEN eventAction = 'end' AND eventLabel = 'success' THEN uniqueevents END ) AS success,
 SUM(CASE
    WHEN eventAction = 'begin' AND eventLabel = 'begin' THEN uniqueevents END ) AS starts
```

I need to calculate the success rate (success/starts) in a new column of my temporary table. I've read a couple of posts that suggest using `group by` but I cant get my head around it.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  If you are using `SUM()` then presumably you already have a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to perform your calculation for success events and starts event, then calculate the final result. Here is the example:

```
WITH
  sample AS (
  SELECT
    'end' AS eventAction,
    'success' AS eventLabel,
    10 AS uniqueevents
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'begin',
    'begin',
    20 ),
  pre_cal AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN eventAction = 'end' AND eventLabel = 'success' THEN uniqueevents
    END
      ) AS success,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN eventAction = 'begin' AND eventLabel = 'begin' THEN uniqueevents
    END
      ) AS starts
  FROM
    sample )
SELECT
  success,
  starts,
  success/starts AS per
FROM
  pre_cal
```